# Select maximum value from a different table as a column

Tags: mysql, sql

There are 2 tables. Table 1 is callsed `Purchases`, it has columns like `Id`, `CustomerName`. Data is like:

```
Id, CustomerName
1 , Customer1
2 , Customer2
3 , Customer3
```

There is also a second table called `Items` with columns `Id`, `PurchaseId`, `ParameterName`, `ParameterValue`. Data looks like:

```
Id, PurchaseId, ParameterName, ParameterValue
1 , 1         , 'Price'      , 100
2 , 1         , 'PercentOff' , 9
3 , 2         , 'Price'      , 200
4 , 2         , 'Price'      , 300
5 , 2         , 'PercentOff' , 4
6 , 2         , 'PercentOff' , 3 
7 , 3         , 'Price'      , 400
```

As you can see, each Purchase can have multiple custom parameters connected to it. For example, Purchase with id 2 has 2 `Price` parameters and 2 `PercentOff` parameters. Purchase with id 3 has only one parameter called `Price`.

I am trying to select the biggest Price and the biggest PercentOff for each purchase. This is how my code looks like right now:

```
SELECT
    p.Id,
    p.CustomerName,
    (SELECT 
        MAX(ParameterValue)
     FROM Items
     WHERE
        p.Id = PurchaseId 
        AND ParameterName = 'Price')
    AS BiggestPrice,
    (SELECT 
        MAX(ParameterValue)
     FROM Items
     WHERE
        p.Id = PurchaseId 
        AND ParameterName = 'PercentOff')
    AS BiggestPercentOff
FROM Purchases p
```

This one works fine, but it's slow as hell. So, how do I get rid of subselects and speed it up a bit?

Note that some of the purchases may have no `Price` whatsoever. In this case, I need to display `NULL`.

I expect to get data like this:

```
Id, CustomerName, BiggestPrice, BiggestPercentOff
1 , Customer1   , 100         , 9
2 , Customer2   , 300         , 4
3 , Customer3   , 400         , NULL
```

Comment: Sample data is great, but you should also specify the expected result.

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this as a join eg

```sql
SELECT
    p.Id,
    p.CustomerName,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ParameterName = 'Price' THEN ParameterValue END) AS BiggestPrice,
    MAX(CASE WHEN ParameterName = 'PercentOff' THEN ParameterValue END) AS BiggestPercentOff
FROM Purchases p
LEFT JOIN Items i ON i.PurchaseId = p.Id
GROUP BY 
    p.Id,
    p.CustomerName
```

| Id | CustomerName | BiggestPrice | BiggestPercentOff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Customer1 | 100 | 9 |
| 2 | Customer2 | 300 | 4 |
| 3 | Customer3 | 400 | *null* |

---

[View working demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/i5bSYwYX7VtFwB3hrrj1UJ/0)

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I had a chance to try it out and just wanted to add some numbers. The query got about 30% faster this way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT id,PurchaseId,ParameterName, MAX(ParameterValue)
FROM item
GROUP BY PurchaseId,ParameterName
HAVING MAX(ParameterValue)  
ORDER BY `item`.`id` ASC
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I do wish I could just use `HAVING`. The thing is, there is about 2mln records in that table. Sadly, there is no way it'll yield better performance.